# Do I really need a code signing certificate for an Outlook Add In?

Tags: outlook-addin, windows-11, code-signing-certificate

I developed an Outlook Add In that we will use internally.
The problem is it gets installed on windows 10 but not windows 11 for some certificate reasons.

Since we will use the add in only internally, do I really need a code sign certificate? Is
there a work around?

Comment: Yes, you do need a certificate for VSTO addins (but not straight COM). You can create your own one, you just need to make sure it is trusted on the machine where your addin is installed. So your need to make sure you can install it under Windows 11. If that is what your question is, do provide more details instead of a vague "for some certificate reasons".

Comment: Yes, that was my question. Would you be so nice to tell if the certificate has to be a code sign certificate?

Comment: What happens when you try to install the certificate under Windows 11?

Comment: similar to this https://mojosoup.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215222463-Outlook-add-in-doesn-t-install-with-message-about-certificate-or-location-not-trusted
with the only difference, we have a local installation/exe package.

Comment: Yes, you need to trust the certificate first. Can you manually install it?